# Open XUL in a new tab/window using Addon-SDK

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, xul, firefox-addon-sdk

It seems possible according to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Guides/XUL_Migration_Guide:

```
you can register a chrome: URI, with a skin and locale, and this means you can include XUL windows in an SDK-based add-on.
```

I added a chrome.manifest as instructed with content:

```
content my_addon content/
```

and put .xul file under chrome/content:

```
myxul.xul
```

then I use tabs.open in main.js:

```
tabs.open("chrome://my_addon/content/myxul.xul");
```

It returns "File not found" as the new tab is opened:

```
Firefox can't find the file at chrome://my_addon/content/myxul.xul.
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the line of the chrome.manifest to

```
content my_addon chrome/content/
```

Comment: cant it be anything? as long its not taken by something else?

Comment: Sorry, my original answer was messed up because I was thinking about the `resource` scheme. It's the syntax of the chrome.manifest that needs correction. I updated my answer.