# interaction between 2 xul windows in extension/addon?

Tags: jquery, firefox, firefox-addon, xul, xpcom

Okay i have 2 xul windows,

```
window_2
<label id="#label_id" value="button has been clicked!">

window_1
[button]---> clicked--> $("#label_id).attr("value","clicked again!");
```

I'd like to change the style(label text) of window_2 when button is pressed on window_1 in xul, i'm using jquery, and this does'nt seem to work, how can i get around this?

Comment: how are you using jquery in an extension? i dont understand. jquery only works in html document scope.

Comment: jquery does work in extensions, no restrictions except for ajax request.

Comment: can you share your work im interested to see how jquery is used with xul i thought the framework is not ready for that and would take a lot of work to adjust

Comment: nothing much to it, just add the jquery library to your xul window, like any other html document and manipulate around.

Comment: on a side note, i keep restarting firefox to test my extension, is there any way the xul or javascript code is not cached? Nglayout.debug.disable xul cache is not available in configuration options in firefox 30

Comment: That's weird I dont know why that is, I dont restart browser to test extension. Are you using loadOverlay? that might have to do with needing the restart

Comment: so how do you keep the javascript from being cached?, everytime i change the javascript in the extension, the browser wont recognise it unless it restarts.

Comment: It shouldn't man, its just like installing one version of an addon and then installing another, it shouldnt cache anything. Don't even need dev environment for it. But set it up according to here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/Setting_up_extension_development_environment#Development_preferences

Comment: @wolfgang have you tried `postMessage`?

Comment: @wolfgang I've been using Addon-sdk to make restartless addons, and here's how to use XUL in them: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22581699/open-xul-in-a-new-tab-window-using-addon-sdk

Answer (score 1):

What you need is get window object of the other window. I could think of a few quick ways to do so:

1. create a module and use it to share window objects of each window:

   **MyWindowModule.jsm**

   ```
   const EXPORTED_SYMBOLS = ["MyWindowModule"];
   var MyWindowModule = {
       window1: null,
       window2: null
   }
   ```

   **window1.js**

   ```
   Components.utils.import("resource://myextension/modules/MyWindowModule.jsm");
   MyWindowModule.window1 = window;
   ```

   **window2.js**

   ```
   Components.utils.import("resource://myextension/modules/MyWindowModule.jsm");
   MyWindowModule.window2 = window;
   ```

   Then you can use in window1:

   ```
   MyWindowModule.window2.$("#label_id).attr("value","clicked again!");
   ```
2. use [nsIWindowMediator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/XPCOM_Interface_Reference/nsIWindowMediator) to find the other window or [other](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Working_with_windows_in_chrome_code) methods of communication between windows